# How to handle Spinners using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In my AngularJS application, for any page to load, there are two things which are loading
First the content of the page and secondly some back-end resources.
While back-end resources are loading, a spinner comes in the front and user is not able to do anything on the page contents.

Now while I am writing the automation test suites of the application using **Protractor**, I am not able to find a technique, to wait for the **spinner** to disappear from the screen before starting the test.

Please help me in this.

Comment: what about waitForAngular https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/8580c0c76c5ccd3c55d053e59d8df37b3c4cf35a/lib/protractor.js#L235

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IsDisplayed` as you mentioned in Andres D's comment should be the right one to use for your situation. However, it returns a promise so you cant just use

`return !$('.spinner').isDisplayed()`

since that will just always return false.

Try the below and see if it works.

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return $('.spinner').isDisplayed().then(function(result){return !result});
}, 20000);
```

Comment: I tried with browser.wait(function () {
var isElementVisible = null;
browser.findElement(protractor.By.className("loadingImg")).isDisplayed().then(function (text) {
console.log(text);
isElementVisible = text;
});
return !isElementVisible;
}, 10000); but this also was not working.

Comment: can you try it the way I suggested? You are returning `isElementVisible` outside of the promise and therefore before the promise is resolved. So it is always returning true.

Comment: This is a good answer. However, it will produce an error if the spinner is removed from the html page (instead of just hidden). If that happens, try: `browser.wait(() => { return $('.spinner').isPresent().then( result => !result ); }, 20 * 1000);`

Answer (score 2):

If you are waiting for something to happen you can use `browsser.wait()`

For example, if the spinner has the class name "spinner"

```
browser.wait(function() {
  // return a boolean here. Wait for spinner to be gone.
  return !browser.isElementPresent(by.css(".spinner"));
}, 20000);
```

The 20000 is the timeout in milliseconds.

Your test will wait until the condition is met.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in the solution you mentioned, it will check only for presence of element in the HTML but my spinner remains in the HTML only and whenever there is a page load it comes into focus first. So even though the spinner is not in the front, wait function will keep on waiting. Can I have something which check if the element is in front of screen or not. I tried the **isDisplayed** function but it did not help and still I am at same place.

Answer (score 0):

For those dealing with non-angular apps:

```
    browser.wait(
      EC.invisibilityOf(element(by.css(selector))),
      5000,
      `Timed out waiting for ${selector} to not be visible.`
    )
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.invisibilityOf