# Test after spinner

Tags: protractor

I'm experiencing same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811579/how-to-handle-spinners-using-protractor) I need to wait site loading and I can know it finihed when spinner goes away and then I need make my tests. But such an easy tests:

```
beforeAll(function(){
    Core.login(env.currentUser).then(function(){
        var foo = browser.wait(function(){
            return !browser.isElementPresent(by.css('.modal .env-waiting-content'));
        }, 50000);
        console.log("page loaded");
        mainPage.navBar.buttons.logIncident.click();
    });
});


it('should work', function(){
    expect(1).toBe(1);
});
```

failed with error:

```
Message:
    Failed: ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
  Stack:
    Error: Failed: ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
        at /home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:104:16
        at /home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
        at notify (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
        at notifyAll (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
        at resolve (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
        at reject (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:545:5)
        at /home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
        at notify (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
        at notifyAll (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
        at resolve (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
        at [object Object].reject (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:545:5)
        at /home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1529:10
        at newFrame.onAbort (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1679:7)
        at [object Object].webdriver.promise.Frame_.notify_ (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1914:5)
        at [object Object]._onTimeout (/home/set/.nvm/v0.10.28/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1887:13)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

- How can I avoid this error and why it occur?
- why `console.log("page loaded");` output message much earlier than spinner disappear and what is the way to execute some code after `when`, some kind of `then` ?
- what is the difference between browser.wait and browser.driver.wait?

Answer (score 1):

Your error looks like a basic networking issue.  Are you able to get the example tests that Protractor ships with working?

The second issue (why `console.log` happens so early) is because Protractor commands do not *do* things, they *queue* things to be done later (promises that the underlying webdriver "control flow" executes).  Read this https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md and https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Understanding_the_API.  So, the console.log ends up running as the steps are queued, not executed.

Generally, in protractor the "top-level" APIs like `browser` and `protractor` and `by` are all "Angular-aware".  The `browser.driver` API is the underlying Selenium webdriver API (which is not aware of Angular).  In the particular case of `wait`, I don't think there is much difference (but I'm not 100% confident of that).